# How to redirect the page to the parent frame?

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am trying to redirect a page to the parent frame. by using the following code.

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('myPage.aspx','_Parent')", true);
```

But this code won`t work in Google chrome and IE. But it works properly in Mozila.
Can any one tell me how can i make this code as browser independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of window.open, use the following:

window.location = "[url]";

If you want the parent window to show the specified URL, use:

window.parent.location = "[url"];

Comment: can you tell me in c# how to use this? I want this code in c#.

Comment: I think you have a typo with quote mark in the second code example.

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "a", "parent.window.location.assign('Test.aspx')", true);